# Google Spreadsheets ImportXML / XPath - I get "data:image/svg+xml..."

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the url of the images from web link.

For this I use the IMPORTXML and XPATH function in google Spreadsheet.
This is the code:

`=IMPORTXML(B1;"//*[@id='gallery-1']/figure/div/a//img/@src")`

So far everything is correct, get the urls of each image, however, I am also getting the following text in turn for each URL obtained.

`data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%20500%20400'%3E%3C/svg%3E`

I don't know how to prevent this text from appearing. I have been looking at the source code of the page link and this text does not appear anywhere. Therefore I consider that it is something related to spreadsheet.

I have checked the xpath again and again but I also find that there is an error ...

Here is a screenshot of what happened for your reference.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tv_zk0JUI9EjCTU0kKfzRuQr936-88I7/view?usp=sharing

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML(B1, "//*[@id='gallery-1']/figure/div/a//img/@src"), 
 "where not Col1 starts with 'data'")
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly! You are a hero! Thank you very much for your help and your time. I mark the answer as resolved and up a vote :)  @player0